# Calling C# Dll from unmanaged C++ application on WindowsCE

Tags: c#, c++, compact-framework, windows-ce, unmanaged

I have an off the shelf product which supports C++ plugins. 
Im wondering if its possible to call a C# Dll from an unmanaged C++ dll so that i can do the grunt work in C# which im familure with and just use the C++ plugin to call and return values from the C# Dll.

Im using WindowsCE which uses .net compact framework which means compiling C++ with the /CLI flag is not an option.

Can anyone explain to me how i can do this. Im not a C++ Developer but im sure i can work it out if im given a simple example.

Ive had a look for something simple like a hello world app online but can find anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it seems like a duplicate. The two answers given seem to indicate its just not possible on WindowsCE. Can anyone else confirm this?

Comment: It can confirm, with no ambiguity, that it is 100% impossible to do what you want with any version of the Compact Framework.

Answer (score 1):

See: [Hosting ActiveX Controls in the .NET Compact Framework 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446515.aspx)

> COM support in the .NET Compact Framework 2.0 is still somewhat
>   limited compared to its desktop computer counterpart. For example,
>   there is no support for external activation. You cannot write a
>   standalone COM component in managed code; if it were possible, a COM
>   component could have been instantiated inside a regular, unmanaged
>   Win32 process. Because managed code requires the Common Language
>   Runtime (CLR) to execute, such setup needs the Win32 process to host
>   CLR. Because CLR hosting is not one of the features of the .NET
>   Compact Framework 2.0, the whole external activation model is not
>   available.